# How to make solr full text search working on custom fields. It is only working on default fields

Tags: xml, solr, full-text-search

Here is what I tried in schema.xml..

For the fields ..

```
<field name="level" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="domain" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="open" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="type" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="sdiv" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="tag1" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="tag2" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="tag3" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="text" type="text_general"  indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

I am using copy fields to copy everything to the text field..

```
 <copyField source="level" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="domain" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="open" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="type" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="sdiv" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="tag1" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="tag2" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="tag3" dest="text"/>
```

Also with only

```
<copyField source="*" dest="text"/>
```

instead of many copy fields. 
I have defined "text" as default field.

But when I search for any text the query works only when the text is in description fields and not in the other fields like tag1,2,3 , type, sdiv etc.. I think it is because description is already there in schema file by default and other fields are defined by me..

This is the code which I am using in schema file to override the solrconfig file...

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
   </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Could you show how you search and add the relevant query handler from your solrconfig.xml? Probably you search with a query handler that defaults to the field `description` and you do not define another field to target the query against.

Comment: We don't have access to solrconfig.xml file as we are using websolr.

Comment: Is it possible to override the default query handler settings of solrconfig.xml file from schema.xml or anything like that..

Comment: Sure, this is why I ask for your query. The solrconfig provides the defaults that will be taken, if nothing else is specified.

Comment: thanks for replying back.. Can you please let me know what should I do to override the solrconfig via schema file as I cannot access solrconfig file. However after your words I tried something like this(code I have added in the above question section and it is starting with request handler... as I can not write it here exceeds max allowed characters) in my schema file but still no go...

Comment: You are saying that `I think it is because description is already there in schema file by default and other fields are defined by me..`.. did you index the data before or after those fields were added?